# Probability understanding 52 C 5

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

Hi I have a problem undertanding this:

Example: In a deck of 52 cards, 5 cards are chosen.

```
What is the probability that all 5 cards have diﬀerent face values?
total number of outcomes = 52 C 5 
total number of face value combinations = 
13 C 5 
total number of suit possibilities, with replacement = 4^5
```

Now I get the 52 C 5, the total number of possibilities, and I get the 13 C 5 the number of face cards in the deck, so:

```
 P( 5 diff face values) = (13 C 5)(4^5)/(52 C 5)
```

Why? What exactly does the 4^5 is doing there? Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the problem easily let's consider that all the five cards are of the same 'type' (either all spade, or all diamond, or whatever you wish). So the face value is different only by the 5 different symbols from the 13 symbols that a particular 'type' of card has.

There are four 'types' of cards- diamonds, hearts, spades and clubs.

Now consider how many combinations of cards (by 'types') can there be with these same five symbols! Each of the five cards can be drawn from any of the four 'types' (diamonds, hearts, spades and clubs) of cards that a deck has. So, there can be 4^5 possible combinations of cards by these 'types' (one card can have 4 possible types, 2 cards can have 4^2 possible types,...and so on!).

That is why 4^5 is being multiplied.

Comment: Can you explain it more?. Say with apples and oranges. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are having confusion in only one part. If we pick two fruits from apple and orange, then there can be actually 4 combinations. You might wonder that 'Apple+Orange' and 'Orange+Apple' are the same things in 'combination-permutation' point of view. But if I assigned two numbers (say, randomly '2' and '5') along with selecting these combinations then are they the same? No they aren't. Then 'Apple+Orange' is actually 'Apple(2)+Orange(5)' and 'Orange+Apple' is actually 'Orange(2)+Apple(5)'. That's why 2^2 combinations are valid. Similarly 4^5 combinations for this problem are valid.

Comment: Welcome @Pedro.Alonso :)